How can I change the black background of the image to grey which has letters in white?
I am trying to change the background of the following image to grey:

This is the code I use:
import cv2 
import numpy as np

img_path = "BUS_img.png"
img = cv2.imread(img_path)

def change_bg_to_grey(image):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    bg = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh)
    bg = cv2.merge((bg,bg,bg))
    result = np.where(bg == 255, (128,128,128), image)
    return result

img_grey  = change_bg_to_grey(img)
cv2.imwrite("greyimg.png", img_grey)

And this is the output from the code:

There seems to be a loss of white pixels from the letters. Is there a way I can preprocess the image in such a way that the letters remain the exact same with no pixel loss and only the black pixels in the background change to grey?
Edit:
I also tried the following code:
def change_bg_to_grey(image):
    grey_bg = np.full_like(image, (128,128,128))
    mask = cv2.inRange(image,(0,0,0), (0,0,0))
    result = np.where(mask[:,:, None] == 255, grey_bg, image)
    return result



output = gray * 0.5 + 0.5

@Nitya Rakhe.  It working on Linux

There are plenty of different ways for this.\
Use cv2.threshold twice; once to get background and once to get the writing. Then combine the images with cv2.bitwise_or.
Here is the code:
import cv2

src_image = cv2.imread('BUS_img.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(src_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,background = cv2.threshold(gray,90,100,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
_,writing = cv2.threshold(gray,90,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
final = cv2.bitwise_or(background,writing)


cv2.imshow('src_image',src_image)
cv2.imshow('final',final)
cv2.imshow('background',background)
cv2.imshow('writing',writing)
cv2.waitKey()


Play with the threshold values to get the exact color and writing thickness you want.
Also check the cv2.threshold function: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html
